# Such as or such...as

Tags: word-order, as

What's the difference between these two constructions?

> 1. The writing class developed skills such as critical thinking, brainstorming strategies, and ways to overcome writer's block.
> 2. The writing class developed such skills as critical thinking, brainstorming strategies, and ways to overcome writer's block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular context there is no significant difference, but in other contexts there may be.

***X such as A,B,C...*** has two significantly different uses. The list *A, B, C* may be either

- **restrictive**: a qualification of X which may not omitted, as if to say **only** or **specifically those X which are like A, B, C**

  > *I prefer playwrights **such as** Ibsen, Shaw and Brecht to playwrights **such as** Wilde and Maetrlinck.*
- **non-restrictive**: an incidental illustration of X, as if to say **for example A,B,C**. When this use is intended, *such as A, B, C* is set off with commas or parentheses.

  > *I prefer politically conscious playwrights **，such as** Ibsen, Shaw and Brecht **，**to mere
  >
  >   aesthetes **，such as** Wilde and Maeterlinck.*

***Such X as A, B, C...***, however "embraces" the X modified within the construction, and thus cannot be used non-restrictively.

> *<sup>OK</sup>I prefer **such playwrights as** Ibsen, Shaw and Brecht to **such playwrights as** Wilde and Maetrlinck.*
>     *BUT NOT*
>   <sup>✲</sup> *I prefer **such** politically conscious playwrights **，**as Ibsen, Shaw and Brecht **，**to **such** mere
>
>   aesthetes **，**as Wilde and Maeterlinck.*

Note that *such* can act as a pronoun, so you may if you like drop the second instance of X:

> *<sup>OK</sup>I prefer **such playwrights as** Ibsen, Shaw and Brecht to **such Ø as** Wilde and Maetrlinck.*

In my own writing I mark the restrictive/non-restrictive distinction a little more systematically by using *X such as A, B, C...* **only** non-restrictively; but I doubt anybody notices, and you are by no means bound to follow my example.

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable*
Ø *marks the point at which a term has been deleted*

Comment: Can I assume that what you've done with the commas here is on purpose, done to draw attention to them?

Comment: I had to read this twice to actually understand what you meant by "restrictive" (I sure hope I *have* understood, because if not I think I disagree!). I assume in #1 you mean the *list itself* is a "necessary" qualifier, insofar as the sentence wouldn't make sense if you omitted the *such as Ibsen, Shaw and Brecht* part. It ***doesn't*** mean that ***only*** items explicitly given in the list are applicable (it's "restrictive" in the sense that only items "similar" to those in the actual list apply).

Comment: ...that's to say, to *my* "inner grammarian", there's something decidedly "iffy" about using "such as" with a list that explicitly specifies every possible qualifying value. Such as *?"This algorithm only works if the input is a non-zero single-digit even integer, such as 2, 4, 6, and 8"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, you've understood me correctly. The *such* informs you that the list is not comprehensive: *only playwrights **who are like** Ibsen, Shaw and Brecht*. But if you have difficulty understanding, others will. I'll rewrite.

Comment: I found this point covered on [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/like-versus-such-as.aspx), where it distinguishes between contexts where *such as* is part of a *nonrestrictive (nonessential) clause*, and where it's "restrictive" (effectively, it *must* be there or we'd have no idea what we're talking about because the context is just too vague). I think it's a wise choice to avoid the "restrictive" usage, because you can never be certain your audience will accurately understand the implied "category type" from any explicitly-listed examples.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I myself usually characterize the category: *such politically conscious playwrights as Ibsen, Shaw, and Brecht*. And I don't much like the *X such as A, B, C* construction (I have no idea why) and say *X like A, B, C* or *(A, B, C for example)* instead.

Comment: Actually, I'm quite fond of using *X such as A, B, C* where the "entry qualifications" for being classified as *X* are a bit vague - particularly when I can't think of a better way to express *X* to reduce that vagueness, ***or*** if I don't know of any other examples, but I don't want my list to be taken as exhaustive.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's much of a difference.

That said, when I read both sentences aloud, there's a bit more emphasis on *skills* in the first sentence. I also have a slight preference for the sound of the second sentence.  (I have no idea whether anyone else shares this preference.)

Comment: While the rest of the answer is (acceptably) subjective, your first sentence is the correct answer: there is no difference. It's purely a literary choice.